# Odoo11 replacing field in sale.report_invoice_layouted with a custom module

Tags: odoo-11

I'm creating a custom module for odoo 11. I would like to add information to the customer invoices. I tried changing the sale.report_invoice_layouted which inherits report_invoice_document. Changes i made in sale.report_invoice_layouted Qweb are visible when printing the pdf. For example I change the field l.name to l.price_unit and this works.

But no I created a custom module and have this template.xml

```
<odoo>
<data>

  <template id="report_invoice_document_tenure_inherit" inherit_id="sale.report_invoice_layouted" priority="16">
    <xpath expr="////span[@t-field='l.name']" position="replace">
            <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
    </xpath>
   </template>
</data>
```

This has no effect at all. Nothing is changed in the printed pdf. I checked "Reload attachment" and it is set to off.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
this is the original sale.report_invoice_layouted which I'm trying to change via module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
<xpath expr="//table/tbody/tr/td[@id='subtotal']"    position="attributes">
    <attribute name="groups">!sale.group_show_price_total</attribute>
</xpath>
<xpath expr="//table/tbody/tr/td[@id='subtotal']" position="after">
    <td class="text-right" groups="sale.group_show_price_total">
        <span t-field="l.price_total" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: o.currency_id}"/>
    </td>
</xpath>
<xpath expr="//table" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="groups">!sale.group_sale_layout</attribute>
</xpath>
<xpath expr="//table" position="after">
    <t groups="sale.group_sale_layout" t-foreach="o.order_lines_layouted()" t-as="page" name="lines_layouted">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Quantity</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Unit Price</th>
                    <th t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">Disc.(%)</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Taxes</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
                <t t-foreach="page" t-as="layout_category">

                    <t t-if="layout_category_size &gt; 1 or page_size &gt; 1" groups="sale.group_sale_layout">
                        <tr class="active">
                            <td colspan="7" style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">&amp;bull;
                                <t t-esc="layout_category['name']"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </t>

                    <!-- Lines associated -->
                    
                    <t t-foreach="layout_category['lines']" t-as="l">
                        <tr>
                            <td><span t-field="l.name"/>
                            <span>TEST</span></td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="l.quantity"/>
                                <span t-field="l.uom_id" groups="product.group_uom"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
                            </td>
                            <td t-if="display_discount" class="text-right" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">
                                <span t-field="l.discount"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: x.description or x.name, l.invoice_line_tax_ids))"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <span t-field="l.price_subtotal" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: o.currency_id}"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right" groups="sale.group_show_price_total">
                                <span t-field="l.price_total" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: o.currency_id}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </t>

                    <t t-if="(layout_category_size &gt; 1 or page_size &gt; 1) and layout_category['subtotal']" groups="sale.group_sale_layout">
                        <tr class="text-right">
                            <td colspan="6">
                                <strong>Subtotal: </strong>
                                <t t-set="subtotal" t-value="sum(line.price_subtotal for line in layout_category['lines'])"/>
                                <span t-esc="subtotal" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': o.currency_id}"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <t t-if="page_index &lt; page_size - 1" groups="sale.group_sale_layout">
            <p style="page-break-before:always;"> </p>
        </t>
    </t>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code:

```
<xpath expr="//t[@name='lines_layouted']//tbody/t/t[2]//span[@t-field='l.name']" position="replace">
    <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Hi Dipen, you changed the two "//" right? I saw this as well yesterday and changed it. also copied your code to try again. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Edit my answer.try to perform this wa.

Comment: I'm getting this error:
`Invalid predicate
None" while parsing None:4, near
<data inherit_id="sale.report_invoice_layouted" priority="16">
        <xpath expr="//t[name='lines_layouted']//tbody//t[@t-foreach='layout_category['lines']']//span[@t-field='l.name']" position="replace">
                <span t-field="l.price_unit"/>
        </xpath>
       </data>`

Comment: I believe this expression `layout_category['lines']']` is causing the problem because of the brackets maybe

Comment: i've change the xpath.also you can try to go with the absolute path.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. Can you explain why my version without lines_layouted expression did not work? I guess it is the nesting of the expression i'm looking for but I'm unsure how to get to your solution next time :)

Comment: There is nothing new it's generated due to of the quotes using on the expression. So it will work but you have to find the exact path expression which causes like starting to replace with first t[name='lines_layouted'] , then body than added more like suitable in xpath so it can be work and you find the mismatch xapth code. So to avoid this process from my side I'll be go with the absolute way to replace this.